# Angular Reactive forms - FormArray - Cannot find control with path error on first load

Tags: angular

Seeing some **Cannot find control with path** errors when trying to use a simple Reactive Form and FormArray.

Component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
this.newForm = this.fb.group({
  currencyExchangex: this.fb.array(
      [this.fb.group({
        rateNumeric: null
      })],

  )
})
```

}

Component.html

```
    <div [formGroup]="newForm">
     <div class="col-md-2" formArrayName="currencyExchangex"
       *ngFor="let item of newForm.controls.currencyExchangex.value; let i = index;">
         <ng-container [formGroupName]="i" >
            <input class="form-control"
             id="rateNumericIdx"
             type="number"
             formControlName="rateNumeric"/>
         </ng-container>
     </div>
    </div>
```

When I first show this component i get the following errors on Chrome Dev tools:

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'currencyExchangex -> 0'
```

and

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'currencyExchangex -> 0 -> rateNumeric'
```

However this error is not displayed if I click out and back to the page showing this component.  Have done lots of debugging (breakpoints and (pre) newForm.value | json (/pre)) and form and relevant controls exist before this error is shown.

Don't like seeing errors so would appreciate any advice to fix it. This was on Angular 8 and also updated to Angular 9.

Comment: put a *ngIf="newForm" in the div new form `<div *ngIf="newForm" [formGroup]="newForm">`. NOTE: no iterate over newForm.controls.currencyExchangex.value, else `newForm.get('currencyExchangex').controls`

Comment: I believe if you move your assignment of this.newForm to your constructor, instead of in ngOnInit(), it should fix your issue. The html is initialized before ngOnInit, but after the constructor. so the html is looking for something that does not yet exist.

Comment: @Eliseo Still the same issue.  With If html is still rendered with error.

Comment: @ChrisReed. Still the same issue when in the constructor.

Comment: There is one open issue in angular repo regarding same kind of issue check this: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35190

Comment: @Chellappanவ Thanks very much.  Certainly looks like my issue.  Would also explain why I've only just started seeing it.

Answer (score -1):

I just started getting this error after updating Chrome to 80.0.3987.100. I think there may also be a chrome bug going on here. My code worked fine in version 79.